# What is the user-flag in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

I've got a homework assignment in which the assignment states that in a procedure, I must:

> - Get a Number from the Keyboard
> - While the user flag is not set
> - Store number in the array
> - inc index
> - get new number from keyboard

My function currently reads

```
mov ah, 09h                     ;reads for $
mov dx, offset arrayprompt      ; Asks for number
int 21h                         ;control given OS

mov ah,01h                      ;read number
int 21h                         ;control to OS
mov count, 0                    ;set counter to 0
mov si, count
```

What is meant by “while the user flag is not set”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "user flag" in x86 assembly. Therefore I'd assume that the flag is meant to be part of your function (e.g. a normal variable) and that whoever wrote the assignment failed to provide adequate details.

For example, maybe the "user flag" variable is meant to be set by your code (breaking the loop) if the user presses Escape or when the array is full.

In any case, I'd recommend asking whoever wrote the assignment what they want, as they're probably the only person that can know.